# Ruby tutorial using "next" and "mod

Tags: ruby, modulus

I just started trying to learn Ruby on another site and it has made sense so far.  But this one has me confused.  The goal was to get the program to display only the even numbers from 20 to 0 using "next".  The tutorial showed the correct code should be `next if i % 2 == 0`, which makes sense, but it kept failing. When I changed the 0 to 1, it worked.

Here is the code that the tutorial showed should work and makes sense to me:

```
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 0   # this is the line that changed
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Here is the code that the tutorial accepted as correct:

```
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 1   # this is the line that changed
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing what tutorial you are following? This is a curious example in a number of respects in terms of learning ruby.

Comment: Please ask only one question unless they are closely related. `next` and `mod` are not related at all, except by proximity in a line of code, which isn't really enough to tie them together in a single question.

Comment: This isn't idiomatic ruby. If this is the level of tutorial on the site I suggest finding another one. [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/), for example is better and you can read it for free online.

Comment: I can't help it: `(0..20).to_a.reverse_each { |n| puts "#{n}" if n.even? }`

Comment: @the Tin Man  I guess my main question is about the mod.  Why did it print the even numbers when it was "if i % 2 == 1" and not work when "if i % 2 == 0"?

Comment: I'd also really recommend finding a different tutorial. The goal of a tutorial is to show the student simple lessons but also to expose them to the language written correctly, i.e., idiomatic code. That one fails badly. The original "[Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)" (AKA "Pickaxe" book) is available for free online and is the best book still. The online version is missing some new stuff but it will get you up and running nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` skips the following code in the loop and go back to the beginning and start next loop. So if you want to show even numbers, you need to skip the odd ones with `next if i % 2 == 1`, vise versa. I wonder what tutorial you are reading...

When `i` becomes 0 in the loop, it meets the condition `i % 2 == 0`, `next` will execute and the `break` check afterwards will be skipped.

One possible change is check if `i` is non-negative (break otherwise) before printing it to console, which results in the following code:

```rb
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 0   # this is the line that changed
  break if i < 0
  print "#{i}"
end
```

To display only even numbers, you should start with `i = 21`, since the first loop will subtract 1 from i so you won't have chance testing `i = 20`:

```rb
i = 21
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 1   # this is the line that changed
  print "#{i} "
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Comment: I got it now.  if i % 2 == 0, it skips the next line, which is the print line.  When I made it i % 2 == 1 it does not skip the print line.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the tutorial was written as it was. I think it wasn't written as clearly as it could have been, and it did a disservice to you by showing code that wasn't how you'd want to write it in real life. Students emulate their teachers, so by showing poorly written code as an example, they teach you to write poorly written code.

Ruby helps us express our ideas simply:

```
20.downto(0) do |i|
  puts i if i % 2 == 0
end
```

is idiomatic Ruby. It's easy to see what is happening:

- we are starting at `20` and counting `downto` `0`
- `|i|` is Ruby's way of assigning the current value of the counter to a variable `i` inside the "block" of code contained in `do` through the `end` statement.
- `puts` is a smart version of `print` that outputs the value of `i` to a line on the display, IF the result of dividing `i` by `2` is `0`. `%` is the "modulo" operator.

Of course there are things left unsaid, such as the proper use of trailing `if` statements, how `puts` looks for trailing line-endings and supplies them, variations on assigning parameters to a block, plus WHY and WHEN we choose to use a method like `downto` vs. a `loop`. At this point at least the student would know to write it like everyone else and wouldn't have to unlearn it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. if i % 2 == 0, it skips the next line, which is the print line. When I made it i % 2 == 1 it does not skip the print line.